# How to requeue messages that never get nacked due to network failure?

Tags: rabbitmq

If a Rabbit MQ consumer receives a message from a queue that has manual acknowledgement but the message gets lost somehow (never gets acked or nacked), is there a way to set a time before the message gets automatically requeued?

Answer (score 0):

This is done immediately, also that's the only thing that makes sense.

The messages remain in the queue until they are ACKed, or until message TTL expires.

Comment: I tested message TTL and if a message is doesn't ack before the TTL expires it just destroys the message from the queue and doesn't requeue it even with manual acknowledgement.

Comment: For the TTL - that's what I said. For requeue, again, if the message is  ACKed, that's it - it's gone. The way the message get's requeued is for exapmple when consumer takes it, and for some reason disconnects before sending the ACK back.